# How to make attach to process macro to attach to Native code?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, debugging

I am using the following macro codeto attach to the debugger:

```
 process.Attach()
```

Works, fine,

but for some reasons it always attaches to the "Managed Code" (sort of default mode I guess)

Is there any way to specify that I want to attach to a "Native code" too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Process2` interface instead of `Process`.  It has the Attach2 method which allows you to specify the types of engines you want to attach with.

Documentation

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.process2.attach2.aspx

Example:

```
process2->Attach2("Managed/Native");
```